# How to load specific index.php file with .htaccess from variable directory structure

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

what if my index.php is in folder root/addbusiness and visitor visit this url: example.com/addbusiness/free or  example.com/addbusiness/free/step
How to load the index.php file from root/addbusiness folder? 
I tried with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/[^/]+/?$ $1/index.php [L]
```

.htaccess file is placed in root/addbusiness folder
Thanks

my root .htaccess file has this code:

```
ErrorDocument 400 error_page.php
ErrorDocument 401 error_page.php
ErrorDocument 403 error_page.php
ErrorDocument 404 error_page.php
ErrorDocument 500 error_page.php
ErrorDocument 502 error_page.php
ErrorDocument 504 error_page.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If .htaccess file is already placed in `root/addbusiness` folder then you just need this rule:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /addbusiness/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This will load `/root/addbusiness/index.php` for every `http://domain.com/addbusiness/...` request that is not resolved to a file or directory.

Comment: no, doesnt work anubhava. With this code it loads my error_page.php file

Comment: yes, with garbage taxt on top I get Internal Server Error

Comment: ok comment out both `RewriteCond` and retest with `http://domain.com/addbusiness/abcd`

Comment: Now works :) Please update it so I can accept it as correct, Thank you !